# Nutanix Collector xls Dummy File

Tags: nutanix

I am currently doing a study to see how best to utilise the nutanix collector .xlsx file, would anybody be willing to share a dummy version of (with no server information) this file?

Also, has anybody tried using an AWS bare metal server to run nutanix on before?

Alternatively, Nutanix have a community test lab if I was to install the collector locally or on an EC2 instance would i be able to collect directly from the test lab prism account?

I appreciate all your support.

Thanks,

Yusuf

I have tried to install a new nutanix environment to do this but i do not have the compute to make this happen.